# ArcGIS Addin disables itself

Tags: arcmap, add-in

I have some custom ArcMap addins that I have built over the last couple of years.  In one specific client environment, the addin installs correctly but when the user clicks the tool to execute it, the tool becomes disabled.  I had this issue before at that site but the user that had it has moved on and I don't recall what he did to fix it.  The users there all use remote workstations and do not have admin rights on them.  I've installed the addin in various ways and made sure that they have the appropriate permissions on the various folders where the addin content sits.  I have also made sure the config is specific to their installed version. The same tools work fine in every other environment I have access to. I have suggested running ArcMap with admin rights to see if this fixes the issue but they do not have those permissions and it is taking weeks to get approval to let them test this option.

Has anyone seen this before and know what is going on?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what code is being run on the onUpdate() event of the button?

Comment: Not much.  Essentially  just set up a couple of things and create an instance of a form and open it.

Comment: ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = null;
                EntryForm entryDialog = new EntryForm(pProps);
                pProps.util.CenterForm(entryDialog);
                entryDialog.ShowDialog();

Comment: Is the "Load all add-ins without restrictions" box selected in the add-in manager?